# Bincount one-hot encoded labels

Tags: python, numpy, one-hot-encoding, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I have a set of one-hot encoded labels and I want to see how many I have of each category. Each label can contain one or more classes like this:

```
[1  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0]
```

my first solution to the problem was to use `np.argmax` and `np.bincount` like this:

```
newLabels = []
for i in range(len(labels)):
    newLabels.append(np.argmax(labels[i]))

newLabels= np.asarray(newLabels)

np.bincount(newLabels)
```

```
array([1221,  722,  199,  918,  599,  678, 1569,  786,  185])
```

but what happens then is that the one-hot encoded example above will be given the value 0 and the second value (that should be 7) is not counted.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Isn't this just the sum of the columns?

Comment: @yatu, you are right! It is just to sum up each column

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

newLabels = Counter()
for label in labels:
    for idx, key in enumerate(label):
         newLabels[idx]+=key
```

The output should be a dictionary where the keys are the labels index and the values are the count.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem is:

```
np.sum(Labels, axis=0)
```